# Angular 6 nested template view

Tags: angular, angular6

I am new to Angular (I am using Angular 6) and I would like to define some "insert content blocks" in my layout views.

For example:

```html
<!-- layout.component.html -->
<div>{{my.title.component}}</div>
<div>{{my.body.component}}</div>
```

Then, I would like to be able to do something like:

```html
<!-- title.component.html -->
<h1>I am the title</h1>
```

And for body:

```html
<!-- body.component.html -->
<p> I am a very complex component inserted up there </p>
```

I would like to then create something like:

```js
<!-- assembled.component.ts -->
@MagicalDecorator({
   layout: LayoutComponent,
   use_as_title_component: TitleComponent,
   use_as_body_component: BodyComponent,
}
```

Can I do such thing? I may be using the wrong approach, but this is how I would imagine it would work. If there is a better approach, I would also like to know.

**Edit:**
the idea is that I want to be able to add formatting using the layout component (e.g., put them in a bootstrap panel) and not have to repeat the same formatting for each combination of components that I want to use with the same layout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at routing?

Routing allows you to define a standard layout container and then just replace what is inside of that container.

For example, you you could define a "app" container (defined with a router outlet) that defines the entire page.

You could define a "shell" container and replace which component is displayed inside of it by simply changing the route.

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Here is another screen shot. This one has three child router outlets. The innermost router outlet is used to display the contents for the particular selected tab.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Yes, I have seen routing, but I was under the impression that you were only allowed one <router-outlet></router-outlet>, which I am already using to change between views.  Is there a way to use multiple instances of routing to change contents at module/component level?

Comment: Yes, you can have nested (or child) routes as shown above. In the picture, the shell router outlet is a child of the app router outlet. You can also have sibling router outlets. I have sample code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/MovieHunter-routing and a video about it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ

Comment: Hi DeborahK, thank you for the video and the code.  This is exactly what I need.  I am accepting your answer

Answer (score 3):

In the 'angular' way you simply create a parent component with 2 child component:

Child components:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector    : 'title-component',
  template : '<h1>I am the title</h1>',
  styleUrls   : ['./title.component.scss']
})
export class TitleComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}
}

import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector    : 'body-component',
  template : '<p> I am a very complex component inserted up there - with an external field of {{}}</p>',
  styleUrls   : ['./body.component.scss']
})
export class BodyComponent implements OnInit {
@Input()
someField;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Parent component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector    : 'assembled-component',
  template : ׳<section>
     <title-component></title-component>
     <body-component></body-component>
</section>
׳,
  styleUrls   : ['./assembled.component.scss']
})
export class AssembledComponent implements OnInit {
  fieldNameOfParentComponent = "Some Formatting";
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

(*)You can use the selectors in any template you want in the application as long as you export these component in the module (lets call it innerModule) and import that module in the module that the component you want to add these selectors to (lets call it externalComponent) is registered on (lets call it.. externalModule).

(**) If you want to use the same component a few time in the same template - use the `*ngFor` directive.
You can also pass input fields into it.
For example:

```html
<section>
      <title-component></title-component>
      <body-component *ngFor="let item in bodyData" 
              [fieldFromOutside]="fieldNameOfParentComponent">
           {{ item.someField }}
      </body-component>
<section>
```

Comment: thank you.  This is the way I thought of, but if I need to use the same layout again and again (let's say, I have 10 components), while only changing one of the components, it wouldn't be DRY.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: @Aba : I hope i understood your demand - Edited the code above.

Comment: no, that is not what I am looking for... I am being a mess explaining what I need.  Let's say I have 10 routes, where I want to use the same layout but (obviously) use different components in said layout.  If I am to use your proposal, I would have to write 10 different layout components (on top of the "real" components, i.e., the ones to be inserted), which would be fine, except that I would need to copy paste all the formatting given in my layout, which is what I would want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Start off by using the `angular-cli` to generate your components, if you have not already done so:

`ng generate component Title`, `ng generate component Body`

Now when you go navigate to the typescript files for each of these components, notice a line that looks something like this:

`selector: 'title-component'`

Inside your `layout.component.html` you will want to put `<title-component></title-component>` to call the component.

EDIT:

If you would like to have an option to use different `title-components` based on a configuration value, you could use `*ngIf`

`<title-component-1 *ngIf="title === 'title1'"></title-component-1>`

`<title-component-2 *ngIf="title === 'title2'"></title-component-2>`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The problem with that is that I would like to use the same layout again and again using different components.  It wouldn't be DRY the way it is proposed.  Let's say I want to use the same layout a few times and this layout has some formatting.  I would then have to repeat the layout's formatting each time I use it

Comment: ah, sorry, I forgot to answer your question: yes, I am using angular-cli to generate components.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn’t you just set a standard layout in the app.component and use nested views in the router file. For each route you could use different components in the various nested routes by changing them in the router config